# PowerShell; confirm text not visible, incorrect colour

Tags: powershell

I have created a custom PowerShell shortcut I use (to set starting folder and run-as admin), but for some reason some colours have also changed from the default.

I managed to fix some of them using these two lines in the profile;

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{"Member" = [ConsoleColor]::Gray}
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{"Number" = [ConsoleColor]::Gray}
```

But the confirm text as seen here is the wrong colour (cant see between 'Yes' and '[?]' and I cant figure it out;
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77jym.png)

Comment: When you run it in a different terminal window or a different computer, are the colors incorrect there too?

Comment: Have you considered setting colours back to default using:   [Console]::ResetColor()

Comment: Tried the reset and it didnt fix it, if I open a terminal via start> Run> powershell, the problem does not exist. Only when running via my custom shortcut. The custom shortcut has a 'target' of "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe powershell.exe -NoExit -command {Set-Location C:\o365\}"

Comment: Could be a difference in the 32-bit or 64-bit version you are activating. One lives in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`, while the other is in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`

Comment: Didnt make a difference, also running '[Environment]::Is64BitProcess' seems to indicate the 'system32' one is the 64bit version. I noticed if I run the 'target' of the shortcut directly in Start> Run, it does not have this problem! So for some strange reason the shortcut is causing this somehow

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix, ended up just creating a new shortcut that pointed to the same target of:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe powershell.exe -NoExit -command {Set-Location C:\o365\}
```

Its colours were wrong again (background was black), but they were just the standard colours I could change from properties> colours, from the console.

The 'faulty' shortcut was the original that came with Windows, where I modified its target. Not sure if its related, also I had 'folder redirection' setup as well which means my $profile location was redirected, not sure if that had an impact either.